# Particles over background image

Tags: html, css

As seen on https://discordapp.com/ there's floating particles overlaying the background of the header. I've searched pretty much everywhere, trying to export transparent videos, gifs from Premiere CC, After Effects even Photoshop, but none of them will work as seen on this page. 
I have also not been able to read through the code to find the source of the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting these using browser dev tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>...) shows that these are a bunch of `<div>` elements, with background images set, using CSS animations to move them vertically, repeating infinitely.

The styles are inline, I've broken one up below for readability.

```
<div
  style='background: url("/assets/6f2ed9d6f802aae1c46620dea14797d2.png");
    left: 0.63%;
    top: 45.41%;
    width: 67px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: Animation5;
    animation-duration: 5.98273s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0.382398s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;'
  data-reactid=".0.2.$=10:0.$=10:0.$=12:0.$=1$point-DISCORD-23:$point-DISCORD-23">
</div>
```

The image used in this style is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I find the animation in their CSS file, I'd be able to use this on my own website?

Comment: Sort of. Their CSS is _inline_ (embedded in the HTML, within each relevant element) so you'd need to copy it from there.